# neo4j-admin import remote file

Tags: neo4j

since neo4j-import will deprecated and not supported in the freature, neo4j-admin import is the recommended way to import data from CSV files, but it seems `neo4j-admin import` not support import not local file, such as URI like HTTP, HTTPS, FTP or HDFS, is that means we have to load all the files to neo4j server local file system?

example:

```
root@zengxijin-VirtualBox:/home/neo4j-community-3.4.7/bin# ./neo4j-admin import --database demo.db --id-type string --nodes "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zengxijin/JavaHub/master/neo4j-tools/neo4j-admin/anticipant_entity.csv"
    Directory of https:/raw.githubusercontent.com/zengxijin/JavaHub/master/neo4j-tools/neo4j-admin/anticipant_entity.csv doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `neo4j-admin import` (like the `neo4j-import`) can only uses local CSV files.